# Silex Class does not exist - Controller

Tags: controller, routes, composer-php, silex

I start on Silex and I can not link my roads to my controllers. I looked at several examples and posts but I blocked, nothing worked.

Currently I have this:
[image: Code_error]

In my index.php

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';


$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$app->get("/", "Silex\Controllers\MainController::index");
$app->run();
```

In my composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "silex/silex": "~2.0",
    "ddesrosiers/silex-annotation-provider": "dev-master"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Silex\\": "silex/"
    }
}
}
```

And my controller :

```
    <?php

namespace Silex\Controllers;

use Silex\Application;

class MainController implements \Silex\ControllerProviderInterface { 

    public function index()
    {
        return new Response('Thank you for your feedback!', 201);
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's important but the url of my project is "silex/".

Can you tell me what is wrong in this code ?
Thank you !

Comment: can you show us the complete error message please, and point out the line where the error come from in your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your file structure path to your Silex namespace should be ""

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Silex\\": ""
    }
}
```

---

It will be better not to use this namespace because it is used by silex framework, that is installed by composer. You can rename it to something else, for example to `App`.

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": ""
    }
}

...

<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use Silex\Application;

class MainController implements \Silex\ControllerProviderInterface { 

...

$app->get("/", "App\Controllers\MainController::index");
```

Comment: Hi, 
I still have the problem.

Comment: Regenerate autoload files `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Hi, 
Not yet ..
This is my code and structure : 

http://imgur.com/a/xqChr

Comment: Is there a problem with the namespace because i've index.php in the /web folder or something like this ?

Comment: Did you run `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: Yes, and when i go http://localhost/App/web/ i've the error : 
"
The localhost page does not work

Unable to process this request via localhost at this time.
HTTP ERROR 500"

But if i comment this line : 
`//$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());
//$app->get("/", "App\Controllers\MainController::index");
`
I've the good error : 
`
NotFoundHttpException in RouterListener.php line 125:
No route found for "GET /"
`

Comment: comment only this line `$app->register(new Silex\Provider\ServiceControllerServiceProvider());`

Comment: uncomment `$app->get("/", "App\Controllers\MainController::index");`, it is a route

Comment: It still does not work

`The localhost page does not work Unable to process this request via localhost at this time. HTTP ERROR 500`

Comment: also try to remove this part ` implements \Silex\ControllerProviderInterface` from your controller

Comment: I've tried on my system, everything works. Do you have trace for this error?

Comment: I don't know .. Cant you upload your test ? And i will show what is the problem/ what is different, and post it.

Comment: I even created a new project using only what you said but with no result. Can you give me your test archive?

Comment: Ok, I will try later

Comment: Thank you very much ! In the weekend if you want :)

Comment: This works fine, the problem was namespace and path errors
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You are using silex 2. Some namespaces have changed.

Instead of `\Silex\ControllerProviderInterface`  you should use `Silex\Api\ControllerProviderInterface`

Comment: I still have the problem :S 

I've in my controller : 
`
    <?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use Silex\Application;
use Silex\Api\ControllerProviderInterface;

class MainController implements Silex\Api\ControllerProviderInterface
{

    public function index()
    {
     return "test";
    }
}`

error : `The localhost page does not work

Unable to process this request via localhost at this time.
HTTP ERROR 500`